# Setup automatice database migration on Heroku after push

Tags: git, github, heroku, database-migration, githooks

I've managed to setup my Heroku app to deploy automatically on a git push to Github. I see that Heroku itself offers [Deploy Hooks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploy-hooks), but those seem meant for integration with other services.

What I'd like to do is see if any changed files containing sql migrations were pushed, and if so, execute a simple bash command performing the latest migration on my Django app, for example in a git `post-update` hook.

How can I set this up on Heroku — I can't see any `.git` folder in my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku's [release phase](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase) is what you're looking for. One of its primary use cases is to run database migrations in conjunction with new releases. You can define a `release` process in your `Procfile`. For example, it might look something like this for a typical Rails app might be something like this:

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
worker: bundle exec sidekiq
release: bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Whereas you would want to swap in the appropriate migration command for your application in the `release` process.